# Problems with zend, call to undefined function libxml

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm starting to use zend framework and trying to submit a form I get this error message:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function libxml_disable_entity_loader() in /usr/local/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Xml/Security.php on line 85**

Someone who can help me please, I thank you in advance. :)

Controller.php

```
public function addAction()
{
    $this->view->title = "Agregar album";
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title);
    $form = new Application_Form_Album ();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Agregar Album');
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($form->isValid($formData))
        {
            $artista_id = $form->getValue('artista_id');
            $nombre = $form->getValue('nombre');
            $fecha = $form->getValue('fecha');
            $descripcion = $form->getValue('descripcion');

            $fecha = $this->fechaMysql($fecha);

            $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Album ();

            $albums->agregar($artista_id, $nombre, $fecha, $descripcion);

            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        }
        else
        {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

Form.php

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Album extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('albums');

        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $nombre = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nombre');
        $nombre->setLabel('Nombre del album:')->setRequired(true)->
            addFilter('StripTags')->addFilter('StringTrim')->
            addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $artista = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('artista_id');
        $artista->setLabel('Seleccione artista:')->setRequired(true);

        $table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Artista();

        foreach ($table->listar() as $c)
        {
            $artista->addMultiOption($c->id, $c->nombre);
        }

        $descripcion = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('descripcion');
        $descripcion->setLabel('Descripcion:')->setRequired(false)->addFilter('StripTags')->addFilter('StringTrim');

        $fecha = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('fecha');
        $fecha->setLabel('Fecha lanzamiento:')->setRequired(true)->addFilter('StripTags')->
            addFilter('StringTrim')->addValidator('NotEmpty');
        $valiDate = new Zend_Validate_Date();
        $valiDate->setFormat('dd-mm-YYYY');
        $fecha->addValidator($valiDate);
        $fecha->setValue(date("d-m-Y"));

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $nombre,
            $artista, $descripcion, $fecha, $submit));
}
```

}

View.phtml

```
<div class="formContainer">
    <?php echo $this->form ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to post the rest of your stacktrace to give more context to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Luke Already update my post.

Comment: Looks like you might need to update to at least 5.2.11 if you are using ZF 1.12 or greater. See my answer below.

Comment: How are you calling this controller? Are you using a route?

Comment: /var/www/zend/practone/application/controllers/AlbumCotroller.php

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is your problem: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12442

Comment: I have the version PHP 5.2.10

Comment: What version of ZF are you using?

Comment: Then the problem described in the above link seems to be your problem as well. Seems you need to downgrade ZF to 1.11 or upgrade to PHP 5.2.11 or later. I'd go with upgrading PHP, since the incompatibility of ZF 1.12 with older versions of PHP seems to be due to a security fix.